# Is it possible to create a MULTI_PICKLIST with Smartsheet Python SDK?

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am trying to create a MULTI_PICKLIST column using Smartsheet's Python SDK, but receive an error saying

"errorCode": 1012,
    "message": "Required object attribute(s) are missing from your request: column.type.",

I'm using the following to try and add the column:

```
column = smartsheet.models.Column({
    'title': 'TEST COLUMN',
    'type': 'MULTI_PICKLIST',
    'index': 0,
    'options': ['One', 'Two']
    })
response = smart.Sheets.add_columns(sheetid, column)
```

Is it currently possible to create a MULTI_PICKLIST Column with Python or has the SDK not been updated to support this? I also tried creating a regular PICKLIST then using update_column to update its type, but I similarly receive an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python SDK has not been updated to support MULTI_PICKLIST. In the meantime you could conceivably use the passthrough option to support creating a MULTI_PICKLIST column. There is more detail in the Python SDK documentation here: https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#passthrough-option

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't even realized that passthrough was an option. This solved my issue and is a useful thing to know.

Answer (score 0):

The Python API docs were updated on 2019-11-08 for MULTI_PICKLIST. There may be functionality there you are looking for.